# How to read properties from an enterprise-POM?

Tags: java, maven

at the moment I have a multi module maven project where versions and plugins are definied in the parent and used in the modules.

Example dependency inside parent.pom:

```
<properties>
  <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And use in module:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This works fine and the project is build without any problems. Now I would like to extract some versions and dependencies into an **independent** enterprise.pom to define them globally and use them in my different projects. So I created an enterprise project (type POM):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myurl</groupId>
  <artifactId>META-POM</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>   
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencyManagement>    
</project>
```

Then I ran `mvn clean install` to put it into my local repository, which worked fine - I can see it there

Next I changed my multi module project to use the META-POM as a dependency (to know about the version definied in the META-POM) and removed the junit-property as well as the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myurl</groupId>
  <artifactId>META-POM</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

When I now try to package my multi module project it failes because the dependencies dont have the properties definied in the META-POM.
Even when I changed the dependency in my module to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

it still gives me the same error `for junit:jar must be a valid version but is '${junit.version}'.`

How can I derive version properties from an enterprise-POM? I want to define them in one place so I make sure I use the same version everywhere.

P.S. I want to have an independenten enterprise-POm without defining a `parent/module` between the enterprise-POM and all multi-module-projects

Comment: You need to add a `<scope>import</scope>` in your dependency to the META-POM. After that you should be able to use the dependency to junit without version tag...

Comment: Yeah you are right! Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `<scope>import</scope>` in your dependency to the META-POM. After that you should be able to use the dependency to junit without version tag.

I recommend to use lower case written artifactId's. And properties in your META-POM only make sense if you have more than one dependency which uses the same version.